# Removing one option from select dropdown generated by jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, select

I am working on a very basic administrator functionality of a social network and I came across this issue of not being able to remove an option from select dropdown list that I previously generated using jquery. The dropdown list contains all users of the social network. Administrator upon clicking on "Delete account" deletes the corresponding record from the database.

Now the question being - when I click on "delete account" it works perfectly fine but the option with a username is still there in a dropdown list and is possible to be picked - when picked it obviously returns dozens of PHP warnings and errors because the record is not in a database anymore. How can I remove this option straight away? I tried something like the following, but it doesn't work.

**admin_panel.php** (only relevant stuff)

```
<select name='users' id='users'>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select user</option>
        <?php
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id <>'".$_SESSION['user_id']."'ORDER BY username DESC") or die(mysql_error());
                $userList = [];
                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                    $username = $row['username'];
                    $userID = $row['id'];
                    $userList .= '<option name="userID" value='.$userID.'>'.$username.'</option>';
                }
            echo $userList;
        ?>
    </select></br></br></div>
    <div id="user_info">
        <!-- generated user info table-->
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 "$('#user_info').on('click', '#deleteAccount', function(e){
    data.command = 'deleteAccount'
    data.userID = $('#users').val()
    $.post(theURL, data, function(result){
        //Do what you want with the response.
        $('#delete_account_success').html(result);
    })
    $("#users option[value='data.userID']").remove();
    $('#delete_account_success').show();
    $('#delete_account_success').fadeOut(5000);
})
</script>
```

**processUser.php** (part of a switch statement)

```
if(isset($_POST['command'])){
    $cmd = $_POST['command'];
    $userID = $_POST['userID'];


$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$userID."'");
$userData = [];
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $userData['userid'] = $row['id'];
    $userData['username'] = $row['username'];
    $userData['name'] = $row['name'];
    $userData['date'] = $row['date'];
    $userData['email'] = $row['email'];
    $userData['avatar'] = $row['avatar'];
    $userData['about'] = $row['about'];
    $userData['admin'] = $row['admin'];
}
 switch($cmd){
 case 'deleteAccount':
        $sql= "DELETE FROM users WHERE id =".$userID;
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        echo "<img src='pics/ok.png' class='admin_updated_ok'>";
    break;
}
```

Comment: $("#users option[value='"+data.userID+"']").hide();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line

```
$("#users option[value='data.userID']").remove();
```

You're removing any option items from #users where the value is equal to the string literal `data.userID`

Try changing it to

```
$("#users option[value='" + data.userID + "']").remove();
```